# SQl Statement Sum

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I am trying to sum these tables and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

My first table is:

```
Reserve
ReserveID   MembershipID   PlayerCount   Time    CourseID
```

My second table is

```
Courses
CourseID   Name
```

My sql statement that I am trying is here:

```
Select Sum(Reserve.Player_Count)Total
From Reserve 
Left Join Courses 
On Courses.CourseID = Reserve.ReserveID 
Where Time = "2012-04-09 07:10:00" 
And Courses.Name = "Lake" (or I had Courses.CourseId = "1")
```

Comment: And what's "wrong" - doesn't give you the answer you want (what answer do you want?)? Gives an error (what's the error)? What are you trying to do? SUm up the number of players for a particular course?

Comment: When I populate the table I am not getting the correct sum.

Comment: Are you sure you are joining this the right way?

Shouldn't this

`Left Join Courses On Courses.CourseID = Reserve.ReserveID`

be more like 

`Left Join Courses On Courses.CourseID = Reserve.CourseID` ?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't joining them correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mixing alias. Avoid them

```
Select Sum(Reserve.Player_Count)Total
From Reserve 
Left Join Courses 
On Courses.CourseID = Reserve.ReserveID 
Where Reserve.Time = "2012-04-09 07:10:00" 
--     ^ Right here  
And Courses.Name = "Lake" (or I had Courses.CourseId = "1")
```

Comment: Starx thanks for the reply, but that still leaves me with the incorrect answer